# Can I encrypt a string such that it can be cracked in a calculable timeframe?

Tags: node.js, encryption, hash

I want to hide a password to make it difficult, but not impossible, to retrieve.  I want to create two programs, one which hashes the password and then other brute forces the answer.  I'm hoping that I can control the length of time that the decryption process takes to something like 24 hours.

I'm most familiar with node.js.

Comment: hashing and encrypting are two different things

Comment: This is rather too broad a question, but try [XOR with different key lengths](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/56281/48805).

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re looking for something called [time capsule cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography), which is based on proof of work systems that require some large calculation to be done before something can be decrypted. I’m not super familiar with how this works, but perhaps knowing that term will help you find what you’re looking for!